# How to achieve overlapping elements with LinearLayout and RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, overlapping

I am trying to use LinearLayout to achieve a layout with several images whose horizontal position are evenly distributed in a certain container of width [A]. As the width of the container shrinks, the images are **supposed to overlap** each-other.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="128dp"                    <--- [A] 
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"    <---- [B]
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout above evenly distributes the images in the container width [A]:

[image: Five stars evenly distributed]

However when changing [A] to some small value that should make the images overlap, they are scaled down to make them fit the width of their parent RelativeLayout. Which is odd, because I explicitly asked a width of `wrap_content` at [B]. I don't want the images to be scaled.

[image: They're scaled down rather than overlap.]

Any ideas how I could make this work?

(The reason why I want the images to overlap is because it's part of the intended choreography during a transition. Their final position will be a non-overlapping one.)

Comment: will be better to understand if you share image/sketch of it

Comment: Nothing fancy, just a few stars beside each-other, like ★★★★★. The above example just shows two. I want the stars to be initially collapsed to a single star (i.e. five stars overlapping each-other), and the transition moves them apart.

Comment: @digorydoo then you must use animations

Comment: I will once the layout works as expected. The idea is that the animation basically changes the layout_width of the parent LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution myself. I found `android:scaleType`, which controls the way how images are scaled with respect to their size. However, using `android:scaleType` did not have any effect at all until I also changed `app:srcCompat` to `android:src`. I have no clue why this is so, but the following works now as expected:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="128dp"
 android:layout_height="64dp"
 >
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     >
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"   <--- !!
         android:scaleType="center"                   <--- !!
         />
 </RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     >
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"   <--- !!
         android:scaleType="center"                   <--- !!
         />
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```